# ASP.NET Response.OutputStream problems

Tags: .net, asp.net, httpresponse

I'm trying to send binary data to a client using Response.OutputStream but seem to be having problems with it. My code is fairly simple and pretty much identical to working code I've used before, but nothing happens on the client when the code runs.

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", genstream.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", filename));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
genstream.Position = 0;

int n;
while ((n  = genstream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) ) > 0)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

If there code there is fine, which it seems to be, what else could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Please describe the incorrect behaviour you are seeing: error message text etc. And read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to help you write questions that can be answered.

Comment: The incorrect behaviour is that nothing observable happens in the browser when the code executes on the server. E.G. The code is run when the client clicks on the a link, but nothing happens when the code runs.

Comment: what does Fiddler show you, are the headers being sent to the client, and is there any body?

Comment: Just downloaded Fiddler and checked it out.. The response is coming through almost identically to the page I have that is working. The only difference in the headers are the content-length, date and server fields, and the one that isn't working has a 'Connection: Close' in there too.

Comment: So I guess a better question would be: Why isn't the browser interpreting the response as a file to download? As I said in the post above, the header is basically identical aside from 'Connection: Close' which shouldn't have any effect?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Response BinaryWrite function and the Flush command. E.g:

```
Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Still no change. It doesn't seem like it's a problem with the sample code I pasted, as I've used essentially the same code before without problem. I'm guessing there's some environment settings that are causing the behaviour but have no idea what.